# python Pyinstaller IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, permissions, pyinstaller

py2exe works good but pyinstaller make this errors

```
ERROR:utils:[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Application Data\\khan\\controll123.exe'

Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Users\Philips\Desktop\filesync\filesyncbaaaaaaaaaaa\client\controll123\out00-PYZ.pyz\utils", line 94, in drop_check

  File "C:\Users\Philips\Desktop\filesync\filesyncbaaaaaaaaaaa\client\controll123\out00-PYZ.pyz\shutil", line 88, in copy

 File "C:\Users\Philips\Desktop\filesync\filesyncbaaaaaaaaaaa\client\controll123\out00-PYZ.pyz\shutil", line 53, in copyfile


IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Application Data\\khan\\controll123.exe'
```

**here is my code**

```
    import os
import sys
from time import sleep
import random
import subprocess
import zipfile

from config import APPDATA

import shutil

import win32api, win32con
import _winreg
import logging





def register_startup(filename):
    try:
        key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",0, _winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
        _winreg.SetValueEx(key, "KSSync",0, _winreg.REG_SZ, filename)
        return True
    except Exception, e:
        return False



            if not os.path.exists(APPDATA):
                os.makedirs(APPDATA)
            dest = os.path.join(APPDATA, "strong_%s.exe" % str(random.randrange(1000,9999)) )

            logger.debug("Copying %s to %s" % (sys.executable, dest) )
            shutil.copy(sys.executable, dest)
            logger.info("Installed %s to %s" % (sys.executable, dest))
            register_startup(dest)
            subprocess.Popen([dest, '--patience'])
            sys.exit(1)
            return True
            except Exception, e:
            logger.exception(e)
            return False
```

The call to register the file in startup These two function produce the error
 register_startup(dest)
  subprocess.Popen([dest, '--patience'])

Yes The file is present 
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\khan\controll123.exe

seems the double back sash are REASON ?

Comment: Have you write permission for the file to be written?

Comment: Yes i do have write permission it works good if compiled with py2exe . but with pyinstaller it give this error msg

Answer (score 1):

Met this problem just now, 
Solved by running the `cmd` with admin mode.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when using pyinstaller, even running cmd as administrator didn't work (personal laptop). What work for me was:

1. check if current user has access to C:\Program Files\WindowsApps (shouldn't have)
2. follow these steps: https://superuser.com/questions/498774/how-to-get-access-to-c-program-files-windowsapps (answered by Matthew wong) to add whoami
3. I restarted my laptop, launch cmd in administrator mode, cd to the correct directory and was able to get pyinstaller --onefile working